# Change dropdown direction according to the free space on screen

Tags: css, reactjs, drop-down-menu

I have an issue with my drop down `sub-menus`. I Have a simple drop down on my header, however it is located too close to window border.

So the `sub-menu` opens beyond window border to the right side and user doesn't see the content of it. Could you please help me to solve this issue?

I know that I need to do some calculations with width or calculate the pixels of free space and if it is less then `sub-menu` width open it on the right side. But I don't know how to perform it.

[image]

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
        (function () {
            handleMenuItems();

            // functions:

            function handleMenuItems() {
                var menuEl = document.querySelector(".menu"),
                    userLinksList = menuEl && menuEl.querySelector(".user-links"),
                    recentlyItemListEl = menuEl && menuEl.querySelector(".recently-visited-item"),
                    favoriteItemListEl = menuEl && menuEl.querySelector(".favorites-item");

                if (userLinksList) {
                    userLinksList.addEventListener("mouseover", function (evt) {
                        var options = {
                            url: "/api/userlinks",
                            method: "GET",
                            successCallback: onloadUserLinks
                        };

                        function onloadUserLinks(result) {
                            if (!window.__RAPMD__) {
                                window.__RAPMD__ = {};
                            }

                            window.__RAPMD__.lastUserLinks = result;
                            createMenuList(result.RecentLinks, recentlyItemListEl, "No recently visited pages");
                            createMenuList(result.Favorites, favoriteItemListEl, "No favorite pages");
                        }

                        if (!window.__RAPMD__ || !window.__RAPMD__.lastUserLinks) {
                            ajax(options);
                        }
                    });

                    userLinksList.addEventListener("mouseleave", function (evt) {
                        if (!window.__RAPMD__) {
                            return;
                        }

                        window.__RAPMD__.lastUserLinks = null;
                    });
                }
            }

            function createMenuList(items, menuItemEl, emptyListTitle) {
                if (!menuItemEl) {
                    return;
                }

                var df = document.createDocumentFragment();

                (items.length ? items : [{ Title: emptyListTitle }]).forEach(function (item) {
                    var li = document.createElement("li"),
                        a = document.createElement("a");

                    if (item.Url) {
                        a.href = item.Url;
                    } else {
                        a.classList.add("empty-link-item");
                    }
                    a.innerHTML = item.Title;
                    li.appendChild(a);
                    df.appendChild(li);
                });

                menuItemEl.textContent = "";
                menuItemEl.appendChild(df);
            }

            function ajax(options) {
                var url = options.url,
                    method = options.method,
                    successCallback = options.successCallback,
                    failureCallback = options.failureCallback,
                    xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

                xhr.open(method, url);
                xhr.onload = function () {
                    if (xhr.status === 200 && successCallback) {
                        var response = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
                        successCallback(response);
                    } else if (failureCallback) {
                        failureCallback();
                    }
                };
                xhr.send();
            }
        })();
    </script>
```

```css
.sub-menu
            background-color: header-sub-menu-background-color;
            color: header-sub-menu-color;
            display: flex;
            justify-content: flex-end;
            height: header-sub-menu-height;
            padding-right: page-side-padding;
            span
              margin: 10px 0;
              display: inline-block;
              cursor: pointer;
            ul
                margin: 0;
                list-style: none;
                display: flex;
                align-items: center;
                justify-content: space-between;
                font-family: font-default-content;
                font-size: font-size-ssm;
                font-weight: bold;
                text-transform: uppercase;
                padding: 0;
                li
                    & + li
                        margin-left: 30px;
                a
                    cursor: pointer;
            ul
                & > li:hover
                    & > a,
                    & > span
                        color: header-menu-active-color;

                    > .arrow-right:after
                            border-left-color: header-menu-active-color;

                    > .sub-menu-list
                        shown()

                    > .sub-menu-list-right
                        showImmediately()
                li

                    .arrow-right
                        cursor: default;

                        &:after
                            pointer-events: none;
                            position: absolute;
                            content: "";
                            width: 0;
                            height: 0;
                            border-top: 3px solid transparent;
                            border-bottom: 3px solid transparent;
                            border-left: 3px solid gray-color-3;
                            display: inline-block;
                            vertical-align: middle;
                            right: 12px;
                            top: 0;
                            bottom: 0;
                            margin: auto;
                    a:hover, span:hover
                        color: header-menu-active-color;

            .main-menu-list li
                position: relative;
                .sub-menu-list, .sub-menu-list-right
                    hidden()
                    display: inline-block;
                    list-style: none;
                    position: absolute;
                    background-color: black-color-1;
                    top: 31px;
                    left: -15px;
                    z-index: $main-menu-sub-menu-list-zindex;
                    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
                    box-sizing: border-box;
                    padding: 0;
                    li
                        position: relative;
                        white-space:nowrap;
                        margin-left: 0;
                        :hover > .sub-menu-list-right
                            shown()
                    a
                        width: 100%;
                        font-family: font-default-content;
                        font-size: 10px;
                        font-weight: 700;
                        padding: 10px 32px 10px 15px;
                        display: inline-block;
                    &:hover
                        color: header-menu-active-color;
                    p:hover
                        color: header-menu-active-color;
                .sub-menu-list
                    min-width: 100%;
                    hideWithDelay()
                a
                    text-decoration: none;
                    display: inline-block;
                    color: gray-color-3;
                .active
                    color: header-menu-active-color;
                .sub-menu-list-right
                    top: 0;
                    left: 100%;
                &:hover
                    .sub-menu-list
                        shown()
                        &:hover
                            shown()
                            .sub-menu-list-right
                                &:hover
                                    shown()
                    span
                        background-color: black-color-1
            .main-menu-list
                li:first-child:nth-last-child(2)
                li:first-child:nth-last-child(3)
                    .sub-menu-list-right
                        left: auto;
                        right: 100%;
```

```html
<ul class="main-menu-list">
            <li class="header-dropdown-item">
                <span class="header-dropdown-item-title">Admin</span>
                <img src="../Layout/images//arrow-down.svg" alt="">
                <ul class="sub-menu-list">
                    <li class="header-dropdown-item">
                        <a class="arrow-right header-dropdown-item-title">Users</a>
                        <ul class="sub-menu-list-right">
                            <li>
                                <a class="header-sub-menu-item" href="/UserManagement/NewUsers?fromMenu=True">New
                                    users</a>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a class="header-sub-menu-item" href="/UserManagement/ExistingUsers?fromMenu=True">Users
                                    management</a>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a class="header-sub-menu-item" href="/contacts-list?fromMenu=True">Contacts List</a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li class="header-dropdown-item">
                        <a class="arrow-right header-dropdown-item-title">Security</a>
                        <ul class="sub-menu-list-right">
                            <li>
                                <a class="header-sub-menu-item" href="/roles?fromMenu=True">Roles</a>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a class="header-sub-menu-item" href="/roles-and-permissions?fromMenu=True">Roles and
                                    Permissions</a>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a class="header-sub-menu-item" href="/column-based-security?fromMenu=True">Column Based
                                    Security</a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li class="header-dropdown-item">
                        <a class="arrow-right header-dropdown-item-title">Notifications Management</a>
                        <ul class="sub-menu-list-right">
                            <li>
                                <a class="header-sub-menu-item"
                                    href="/email-notifications-management?fromMenu=True">Email Notifications</a>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a class="header-sub-menu-item" href="/sent-email-notification?fromMenu=True">Sent Email
                                    Notifications</a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li class="header-dropdown-item">
                        <a class="arrow-right header-dropdown-item-title">Source Data Analysis</a>
                        <ul class="sub-menu-list-right">
                            <li>
                                <a class="header-sub-menu-item" href="/automated-error-logging?fromMenu=True">Automated
                                    Error Logging</a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li class="header-dropdown-item">
                        <a class="arrow-right header-dropdown-item-title">Technical Services</a>
                        <ul class="sub-menu-list-right">
                            <li>
                                <a class="header-sub-menu-item" href="/ddl-management?fromMenu=True">Dropdown Lists</a>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a class="header-sub-menu-item" href="/unconventional-tags?fromMenu=True">Unconventional
                                    Tags</a>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a class="header-sub-menu-item"
                                    href="/lcs-po-item-matching-duplicates?fromMenu=True">Tag Matching Duplicates</a>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a class="header-sub-menu-item" href="/3-digit-code-register?fromMenu=True">3 Digit Code
                                    Register</a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
```